# xml login script using php

Tags: php

I am trying to find a tutorial for login script using a XML file I have searched the web but nothing seems to fit my requirements here is a sample of my XML file any help would be most appreciated

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>
<MYData>
    <login_details>
        <unique_ref>1-61</unique_ref>
        <login>me</login>
        <password>me</password>
        <file1/>
        <file2/>
        <file3/>
        <file4/>
    </login_details>
</MYData>
```

Comment: DOMDocument http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php. Also, why are you using `Windows-1252 encoding`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to read the child password tag (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp) and then compare to what your user input.
However...are you sure of this approach? For security instances why not leave this task to the WS that provides that XML file and you pass the user input as a parameter? Even encrypted in some way...and then the WS returns true or false in case the password matched or not